# SAP Fiori Launchpad Timeout Shell Plugin app - has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: ajax, sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform

I've implemented a Fiori 'Shell Timeout" to disable the Timeout on the SAP Cloud Platform Launchpad.

The Shell plugin app is called fine when deployed to our Fiori Launchpad.

However, the AJAX call within the app is erroring out with

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://launchpadtimeout-xxxxxxx.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/?_=1573041816189' from origin 'https://flpnwc-xxxxxx.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My app was put together using this [documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/8422cb487c2146999a2a7dab9cc85cf7/Cloud/en-US/87764543e31247b5b471c06e3f6da6fc.html) (SAP Help Portal > SAP Cloud Portal Service > SAP Fiori Launchpad Sites > Creating and Configuring Shell Plugin Apps).

I've tried to add DESTINATIONS in SAP Cloud Platform to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

uri was the fiori Launchpad uri of the app as opposed to it's SCP uri.